# Can I add message to CMake so it would appear during the make (build) and not during cmake (makefile generation)?

Tags: makefile, cmake

I try to search for this kind of option, unable to find it. Don't want to read all the CMake documentation (a lot of reading), maybe somebody  knows and can answer fast. Thank you.

Comment: While I can understand one can have trouble with dealing with issues, I definitely cannot agree with 'I-don't-want-to-read-let-sb-else-do-it-for-me' kind of approach...

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing. Create a custom target with `ALL` keyword that runs CMake executable in command-line tool mode:

```
add_custom_target(PrintMessage ALL COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo blabla)
```